# Widlfy 8.2 CLI Datasource Setup

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am trying to set up a MySQL Datasource for a Wildfly 8.2 and need to add a connection-property to the data source.

The connection-property is the tag in the `standalone.xml`.

CLI Command:

```
data-source add --name=mysqlDS --driver-name=mysql --jndi-name=jndi
    --connection-url=url --user-name=user --password=password
```

Whats the command argument to add the connection property and how to set it up?

Comment: Have you tried `data-source add --help`?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I checked it now and I see --connection-properties is the argument. Its marked as string, but I have a key value pair to be passed. Do you know the format that I need to use?